# AWS API stage name forgotten during form submission

Tags: python, html, flask

I've started making a simple website on AWS Lambda with the following form

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="file">Upload Document:</label>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" accept=".docx" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"
    placeholder="Enter your email address" required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send for Review</button>
</form>
```

Instead of being sent to
https://abcd1234.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/v0/upload

I am sent to
https://abcd1234.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/upload

What can be the cause of this issue ?

EDIT:
Here is the flask app I use on Lambda:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import awsgi

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    return

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return awsgi.response(app, event, context, base64_content_types={"image/png"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

> `action="/upload"`

This is a URL relative to the document root (https://abcd1234.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com)

You need to either put a full root-relative path to the form processor URL:

> `action="/v0/upload"`

or make it relative to your document (the URL in the address bar in the browser).

The latter may look like `v0/upload`, `upload`, `../upload`, etc, depending on what your HTML document URL looks like. Note the absense of the slash in the beginning.

If you page URL is https://abcd1234.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/v0 (without the trailing slash), then the relative URL to the form handler would be `v0/upload`. Had it been `https://abcd1234.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/v0/` (with the trailing slash), the form URL would be `upload`. It's a very common problem, and it sucks.

Comment: Using "/v0/upload" works, but it means that I need to change my html documents as per the stage name (v0 in this case) every time I change the API stage, isn't there something more convenient ? The other solutions send me to the same wrong address.

Comment: @Gettippi: there is something more convenient, it's called "document-relative URLs", which is my second suggestion. What is the URL of your HTML document which renders the form?

Comment: https://abcd1234.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/v0/
I have tried your other solutions, they all send me to the same wrong address (without /v0/)

Comment: @Gettippi: relative URLs without trailing slash are a pain in the ass. There are ways to deal with it, but you'll have to post it as another question, because this one is already way off the original topic.

Comment: I do not even understand where it comes from: it is working on a local environment but not on AWS lambda

Comment: @Gettippi: something on your working environment is adding the trailing slash to the document URL. It's a very common pattern. Try manually adding the slash to the lambda URL

Comment: I've added the rest of my code, I did not find anything that would add a slash. If I were to add it manually, where should I do so ?

Comment: @Gettippi: in your browsers' address bar